# To see virtual filesystems in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

**How can you see the virtual filesystems at root?**

They should be /proc and /dev.

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: My fried said to me that all Ubuntu's virtual filesystems are at /dev and /proc. My question is based on his statement.

Comment: that's not all; there's also *sysfs* at */sys* and *tmpfs* at */tmp* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masi I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

To see a recursive detailed listing of all the files in /dev, page by page:

```
$ ls -laR /dev  | less
```

To see a recursive detailed listing of all the files in /proc, page by page:

```
$ ls -laR /proc | less
```

Was that what you were looking for?
-pbr

Answer (score 1):

You mean like cat /proc/filesystems ?

Or just a mount ?